# Why some Rails methods query database when I have the collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

quick Rails questions.

So I have a collection, retrieve from database, something like:

```
a = Invoice.all
```

Then I want to have the sum of all the amounts on that collection:

```
a.sum(:amount)
```

It works and returns the proper value, mu question is, why Rails makes a second call during the `.sum()` part, when it already has access to the whole collection and could just look at the records from the collection?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I have a collection, retrieve from database
>
> ```
> a = Invoice.all
> ```

Nope, that is not an "inflated" collection (it doesn't contain any objects). It's a relation/query object instead, describing what kind of objects satisfy this query.

If these are the only two lines in your code, there will be only one query, the `sum`. If you see a second query, must be there's some other code which loops on invoices (or something like that)

```
a.each do |invoice|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. after doing `to_a` can I still use `.sum()`?

Comment: @RomainGonçalvès: nope. That is now an array, not AR relation object (and, as a consequence, it does no longer have AR relation api). But you can use array/enumerable methods for summing.

Comment: Alright, thanks @sergio-tulentsev I guess that answers my questions. Is there maybe a library that decorates records retrieved from DB and give us some sugar to manipulate that data? I'll accept your answer once I can.

Comment: @RomainGonçalvès: enumerable api is very versatile as it is. Take a look at the docs, you'll be amazed at what it can do.

Comment: once you have them loaded just use `a.map(&:amount).inject(0, :+)`

Answer (score 3):

`.all` does not actually load the records. Rather it gives you a scope which is lazy loading.

`ActiveRecord::Calculations` uses the database to get aggrregates such as sums. Doing the same operation using Rubys enumerable module may give very different results which is why loaded collections do not provide a `sum` method which matches the signature.

```
if a.loaded?
  a.sum(&:amount) # use Enumerable#sum
else
  a.sum(:amount) # use ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One point to remember is

```
a = Invoice.all
#=> SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices"
```

whereas

```
a.sum(:amount)
#=> SELECT SUM("invoices"."amount") FROM "invoices"
```

Both statements will fire an ActiveRecord query because that's the way rails works. `sum` will fire a different query with `SUM("invoices"."amount")`

If you don't want to fire ActiveRecord query you can make use of `Array#sum`

```
a.map(&:amount).sum
#=> 1234
# OR
a.to_a.sum(&:amount)
#=> 1234
```

Comment: You can avoid map by passing a block or method name to sum.

Comment: Then we will have to convert the result to array first or it will break